# facebook social plugin 'Like box' doesn't display posts from fans

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I am using the Facebook Social plugin 'Like Box'  (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) on a web application I am creating in asp.net.

The plugin only displays the posts that the page Admins have posted but doesn't show the posts that were posted by the Fans (Users who have liked the page).

Does anyone know if there is a workaround this or is this like this by design?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You can't get "Posts By Others" in the like box.

If you own an app you can get each and every wall posts on a page but then you have to take the headache of parsing and formatting it.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=your_access_token